# Looping through a 2d array Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I'm slightly confused about something, I was looping through a 2d array just experimenting when I came up with this code:

```
result = [["Lucas","5"],["Tim","2"]]
count = 0
for line in result:
    for item in result[count]:
        print(item)
        count = count + 1
```

What I thought this would do is give me a result of `Lucas` and then `2`, as it would go to the first item, then the second `for` loop would go through the sublist, printing `result[0][0]`, yet once it had got to the first item of the sublist, it would increase the count to 1, meaning it would print `result[1][1]` next, as it is under a new scope but the loop is then going to the second item of whatever scope it is under.

However, this would give 'Lucas','5' as an output. I thought when I change the count, I thought I was changing the scope that it is looping through.

Please explain to me why I am wrong

Thank you in advance, and apologies for not explaining this very well.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
for item in result[count]:
```

the expression `result[count]` is only evaluated once, at the beginning of the loop. It's not evaluated each time through the loop, so reassigning `count` has no effect on subsequent iterations. It's roughly equivalent to:

```
temp = result[count]
for item in temp:
```

Remember that the value you're looping over with `for` could be a generator expression. These can't be indexed, they just calculate a series of values. So it wouldn't make sense to re-evaluate them each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in result:
```

will loop through the top level arrays, so there are 2 records here: `["Lucas","5"]` and `["Tim","2"]` Then:

```
for item in result[count]:
```

will loop through each item for each of the 2 records, so

```
print(item)
```

will display 4 items,  in the order `Lucas, 5, Tim, 2`.

There is no need for count, it serves no purpose here, and is not used by either of the for loops in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using for loops you can also use

```
result = [["Lucas","5"],["Tim","2"]]
count = 0
for line in range(len(result)):
    for item in result[line]:
        print(item)
        count = count + 1
```

returns : Lucas
5
Tim
2

Answer (score -2):

There is no need for a `count` variable. `result[count]` gives you the first item because you set `count = 0`, so you are really just looping through `["Lucas", "5"]` in your inner loop. You can just use two `for...in` loops

```
result = [["Lucas","5"],["Tim","2"]]
count = 0
for line in result:
    for item in line:
        print(item)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Useful to know, but doesn't answer my question - should of been a comment